# Solid background behind a rotated image in pure CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way i can draw the black "background" behind the image using pure CSS ?

I am persuaded that it can be done using the `:before` pseudo-class. But i can't make it work. I have also tried using shadows, but the final result is not similar what i am trying to achieve.

**Scope and requirements:**

Modern browsers, no javascript, no jQuery, no plugins and no extra HTML markup.

**Before answering:**

I know there are zillion ways to achieve what i am trying to do, however i am really looking forward for a pure CSS solution. As stated before, trying to avoid extra markup and javascript for something as simple as that. Thanks!

[image]

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfBWb/1/) and the code below.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  -moz-transform-origin: center left;
  -ms-transform-origin: center left;
  -o-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
  transform: rotate(-2deg);
}
img:before {
  background: #000;
  -webkit-transform-origin: center left;
  -moz-transform-origin: center left;
  -ms-transform-origin: center left;
  -o-transform-origin: center left;
  transform-origin: center left;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
  transform: rotate(-4deg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  content: ".";
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body>
  <img width="300" height="150" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Example.png" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Make sure you test this thoroughly in different browsers. I recently tried rotating an image using CSS. In Chrome it looks less-than-ideal (although I think the last version fixes the problem), and in the iPad it looks completely horrible (the edges don't anti-alias at all). Look [here](http://www.css-101.org/articles/-webkit-transform-rotate-and-anti-aliasing/rotate-creates-jagged-border-image.php)

Comment: It's not a quality problem. It's just about making it work. If i was worried about quality, i would have exported my image rotated with the black frame behind.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of the requirements? Do you want the box to in a different angle? If now you just could use box-shadow.

Comment: Yep, i need the box with a different angle. The shadow makes a paralleled box behind the image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like the before: element is ignored on img tags - http://jsfiddle.net/GVdYe/

Added a div (sorry :-)

Comment: Thanks! I can live with that :p

Answer (score 3):

The problem you're having is related to how pseudo-elements work.

Before and after elements are rendered inside their parent. So:

```
 div:before{ content:'before'; } 
 div:after{ content:'after'; }
```

renders basically like this:

`<div> <span>before</span> Hello <span>after</span> </div>`

You can't put other elements in `img`, because `img` is a replaced element, and therefore can't apply pseudo-elements to it. [Read the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#before-after-content).

So, the easiest option would be to wrap the image in an `<a>` (as images sometimes are) and apply your before style to the `a`.

Alternatively, accept the non-rotated shadow `box-shadow` provides.

CSS has limitations unfortunately, so you're going to have to compromise somewhere, either in design (I would argue this is the way to go) or in markup.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation :) Cheers! I didn't know that browsers rendered those pseudo-classes INTO elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
html (or body) {
    background: url();
}
</style>
```

I don't know if you just want it behind the image or the entire browser. If you want it behind the image only then you will need a wrapper or at least another `<div>`, `<span>` or `<img>`